# Creating a PDA that accepts the following language

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata, python

Using automata-lib 5.0.0 (Python library), I need help creating a Python program that simulates a PDA that only accepts the following language:

L = {a^m b^n | 0 ≤ m != n}

If you could provide any diagrams, or flowcharts to help me understand, they would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a routine exercise. You don't need our help to solve it.

Comment: Please search for an answer before asking https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Cases
M>n
M<n

The union of these cases will give you  answer